# How to get GUI application to run on the cloud?

Tags: ubuntu, gui, vnc, oracle, blender

**How to run Blender GUI on headless Oracle Cloud through VNC?**

The compute must be `VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro` (AMD processor) or `VM.Standard.A1.Flex` (ARM processor). Both can be tried on their free tier. I am using the Ubuntu 22.04 image.

## When through terminal

It works without problems:

```
> sudo apt-get install -y blender

> blender --version
Color management: using fallback mode for management
Color management: Error could not find role data role.
Blender 3.0.1

> blender test.blend --background --render-frame 1 --render-output '/tmp/out_####' -F PNG --engine CYCLES -noaudio
Fra:1 Mem:42.93M (Peak 44.01M) | Time:00:03.10 | Syncing Cube
Fra:1 Mem:42.96M (Peak 44.01M) | Time:00:03.14 | Syncing Light
Fra:1 Mem:42.96M (Peak 44.01M) | Time:00:03.14 | Syncing Camera
Fra:1 Mem:42.96M (Peak 44.01M) | Time:00:03.30 | Rendering 1 / 4 samples
...
```

## When through SSH X11 forwarding

It works without problems, except that it is excessively slow:

```
$ ssh -X user@ip_address

> sudo apt-get install -y blender
> blender
```

Starting Blender takes a whole minute, and closing the startup window takes 10 seconds. Moving around takes 10 seconds too.

## When through VNC over reverse SSH tunnelling

```bash
$ ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 user@ip_address

> sudo apt-get install -y blender freeglut3 tightvncserver xfce4
> tightvncserver -nolisten tcp -localhost :1
```

and then running `blender` through the VNC GUI:

```
> blender
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
./intern/ghost/intern/GHOST_WindowX11.cpp:136: X11 glXQueryVersion() failed, verify working openGL system!
initial window could not find the GLX extension
Color management: using fallback mode for management
Color management: Error could not find role data role.
Color management: scene view "Filmic" not found, setting default "Standard".
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
```

and downloading [latest version of Blender from the website](https://www.blender.org/download/release/Blender3.5/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64.tar.xz/):

```
> ./blender
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1".
Error! GLX_ARB_create_context not available.
Error! GLX_ARB_create_context not available.
Error! GLX_ARB_create_context not available.
Error! GLX_ARB_create_context not available.
Error! GLX_ARB_create_context not available.
Error! GLX_ARB_create_context not available.
Error! GLX_ARB_create_context not available.
Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.
```